# How to solve "useEffect has a missing dependency"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a project where the data is been fetched from Firebase and the whole UI is working fine but a error is coming which is

```
Compiled with warnings.

src/Myproject.js
  Line 16:7:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchDB'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

but if we see the code

```js
// Code...
const [allProjects,getAllProjects] = useState([
        {
            coverImg: null,
            dateOfpublish: "--/08/2021",
            demo: null,
            summary: "To showcase my skills",
            tag: "react",
            title: "Portfolio"
        }])
    const fetchDB =  async() =>{
        const getdata = db.collection('projects');
        const data = await getdata.get();
        data.docs.forEach(project=>{
            getAllProjects([...allProjects,project.data()])
        })
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchDB();
    },[])
// Code...
```

I can't find where it is going wrong...

> this issue is closely related to this [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook)
> but still, the solutions are given there are still not fixing my issue.

*Whole code is there on [Github](https://github.com/Sukarnascience/MyPortfolio)*

Comment: `   },[])` means that the useEffect only runs once, but you're using state which at first will always be `[]`.

Comment: What's your goal? Calling `fetchDB` once the first time the component renders? Or call it multiple times? If so, when/how? Please elaborate.

Comment: @FelixKling Sir, I want to fetch all the data once when the UI loads not multiple time

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error because fetchDB function will create every render and react is trying to warn you about if fetchDB was changed useEffect won't trigger after changes.

There are two ways to prevent this.
First you can create the fetchDB function inside the useEffect like this.

```
    useEffect(()=>{
      const fetchDB =  async() =>{
        const getdata = db.collection('projects');
        const data = await getdata.get();
        console.log(data)
        data.docs.forEach(project=>{
            getAllProjects([...allProjects,project.data()])
      })
    }
      fetchDB();
    },[])
```

On the otherhand, You can use useCallback hook to prevent create fetchDB on every render with memoization

```
 const fetchDB =  useCallback(() => {
    async() =>{
        const getdata = db.collection('projects');
        const data = await getdata.get();
        console.log(data)
        data.docs.forEach(project=>{
            getAllProjects([...allProjects,project.data()])
        })
    }
}, [])

 useEffect(()=>{
    fetchDB();
 },[fetchDB])
```

Comment: By using your solution another issue has rised that fetchDB is called again and again

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```js
const [allProjects,getAllProjects] = useState([])
    const fetchDB =  async() =>{
        const getdata = db.collection('projects');
        const data = await getdata.get();
        console.log(data)
        data.docs.forEach(project=>{
            getAllProjects([...allProjects,project.data()])
        })
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchDB();
    },[fetchDB()])
```

I would also rename

```js
const [allProjects,getAllProjects] = useState([])
```

By

```js
const [allProjects, setAllProjects] = useState([])
Or
const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])
```

And on your GitHub everyone can have access to your api keys and credentials. You should store sensitive informations in a .env or .env.local file and add this file to your gitignore.

Comment: `[fetchDB()]` is not correct, you don't want to use the return value of the function in the dependency array. The other problem is that `fetchDB` will be called every time the component renders (not only the first time) because `fetchDB` changes on every render.

Comment: @FelixKling Sir Please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

This error has kept me up for days before I found a solve for it which is

```
 const fetchDB =  useCallback(async () => {
        const getdata = db.collection('projects');
        const data = await getdata.get();
        data.docs.forEach(project=>{
            getAllProjects([...allProjects,project.data()])
        })
}, [getAllProjects, allProjects])

 useEffect(()=>{
    fetchDB();
 },[fetchDB])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by adding EventListener at the load

```js
const [allProjects,getAllProjects] = useState([]);
    const fetchDB = () =>{
        db.collection("projects").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(element => {
                var data = element.data();
                getAllProjects(arr => [...arr,data]);
                console.log("is called")
            });
        });
    };
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchDB()
    },[])
```